# Max inline action depth per transaction reached on simple EOS transfer action call?

Tags: cleos, eosjs, eosio-code

I am seeing the error

```
Error 3040000: Transaction exception
Ensure that your transaction satisfy the contract's constraint!
Error Details:
max inline action depth per transaction reached
```

after a simple call to an EOS transfer action

```
cleos -u http://api.eosnewyork.io:80 push action eosio.token transfer '{"from":"aromaticbeer", "to":"polyeosiswin", "quantity":"0.1000 EOS", "memo":"jbj"}' -p aromaticbeer@active
```

Here is my inline transfer action code in the polyeosiswin smart contract on the mainnet:

```
    if (quantity.symbol == EOS_SYMBOL)
{
    name eosio_name = "cooperbaxter"_n;
    asset amount = asset(10000, EOS_SYMBOL);
    action (
            permission_level{_self, "active"_n},
            "eosio.token"_n,
            "transfer"_n,
            std::make_tuple (
                from = _self, to = eosio_name, quantity = amount, memo = "Test"
            )
        ).send();
}
```

This is too simple to be seeing an error. What gives?

Comment: have you found the root cause ? i got this error occasionally as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

Changing the if statement to...

```
if (latestRecord.account.name != _self)
```

did it. A check to see if the contract
is not the receiver of the tokens is necessary.